# Why am I allowed to set the value of an NSNumber to true/false in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
var num = NSNumber(bool: false)
num = true
println(num) // "1"
```

`num` is an `NSNumber` instance, while `true` is a `Boolean` instance. Why is this allowed, and how does it work?

I have a feeling it implements some kind of converters, and so if that is the case, how would I implement arbitrary converters for my custom class?

Comment: Because of the conversion outlined in @pNre's answer, your first line could also be `var num:NSNumber = false` or `var num = false as NSNumber`.  The latter form is especially handy when you're putting Swift primitive data types into `NSDictionary`s.

Answer (score 4):

`NSNumber` can contain both numbers (int, float, ...) and booleans.

In Swift standard library the `Boolean` type implements the conversion to `NSNumber`, you can do the same adding a `func __conversion()` method to your classes, like this:

```
class MyNumber {
    func __conversion() -> NSNumber {
        return NSNumber(float: Float.infinity)
    }
}

var i = NSNumber(int: 1)
i = MyNumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason here is that you are using an Objective C class NSNumber.

The init here is mapped on to its class methods in this case using a bool maps it onto [numberWithBool:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-numberWithBool_)  In Objective C Bool is a char with @defines for tee and false so the Swift false is mapped to 0 and true to 1

Answer (score 0):

> while `true` is a `Boolean` instance

Not necessarily. It can be any type that conforms to the `BooleanLiteralConvertible` protocol. `NSNumber` does conform to this protocol (as well as to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` and `FloatLiteralConvertible`).